# 404 Error when loading dependencies in web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sails.js, bower

I have a working SailsJS boilerplate app. I am trying to add Angular-Material as a dependency so that I can start some UI work. Hmmm...

I have installed angular-material with bower and then added references to the files e.g.:

```
<link href="./bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

As you can see from this file tree in Sublime, I believe that path is valid?

[image]

However, when I run my page, I get loads of 404 errors in the console. If I try to open `http://localhost:1337/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css`, then I get a 404 page. Why is this happening?

Comment: I guess that the base URL is mapped to a different directory. Just hit http://localhost:1337/ and check to which directory it is mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use: `angular-material.min.css`

```
<link href="./bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

---

Depends on what server you start to serve on your localhost, needs to have more details.